# lightgallery.js multiple instances not working

Tags: jquery, html, lightgallery

I am trying to use ["LighGallery.js"](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html) in my page.

**Situation:** I have several groups of images and each group should be displayed in its own gallery.
For each group, there is 1 image visible, and the rest are hidden and are to be shown in a gallery when the first visible image is clicked.

**Problem:** The gallery triggers for the only the first category. It does not triggers gallery view for the rest of the images.

**Question:** How can I use multiple instances of galleries. I can't seem to figure it out from the documentation. Anyone worked on this before?

**What I have tried:** I read around and tried using the *Hash* plugin that comes along. It still did not work:

Code structure:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="topleft">
  <!--Gallery 1st picture triggers-->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="gthumbnail gallery1" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="gthumbnail gallery2" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!------------------->

  <!--Individual galleries surrounded by DIVs-->
  <div>
    <a class="gallery1" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
    <a class="gallery1" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a class="gallery2" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
    <a class="gallery2" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <!------------------->
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
$(".topleft").lightGallery({
  thumbnail: true,
  hash: true,
  galleryId: "gallery1",
  selector: '.gallery1'
});

$(".topleft").lightGallery({
  thumbnail: true,
  hash: true,
  galleryId: "gallery2",
  selector: '.gallery2'
});
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX:

```
<div class="topleft--g1">
<div class="topleft--g2">
  <!--Gallery 1st picture triggers-->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="gthumbnail gallery1" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="gthumbnail gallery2" href="http://lorempixel.com/320/240"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(".topleft--g1").lightGallery({
  thumbnail: true,
  hash: true,
  galleryId: "gallery1",
  selector: '.gallery1'
});

$(".topleft--g2").lightGallery({
  thumbnail: true,
  hash: true,
  galleryId: "gallery2",
  selector: '.gallery2'
});
```

P.S. hash: true <- delete it. 
'True' by default https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#lg-hash

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different id's for different gallery on same page because reading on github, there already is an open issue. for more detail you can check here [github](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/319)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more programmatic way, you can use this solution. I used groups for the same links but different tags and I used vanilla [lightgallery.js](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/)

You can find a working example at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mv09tuy2/2/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-multiline">
    <div class="column is-full">
      <h2 class="title has-text-centered">TITLE</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-1" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2><a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-2" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum dolor site amet</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-1" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2><a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-2" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum dolor site amet</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-1" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2><a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-2" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum dolor site amet</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-1" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2><a class="light-gallery light-gallery-single" data-group="light-gallery-2" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum dolor site amet</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var $galleries = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.light-gallery'));

if ($galleries.length > 0) {
  var lightGalleryOptions = {
    mode: 'lg-soft-zoom'
  };

  // Check first element have light-gallery-single class
  // Used for more control over light-gallery instances
  if ($galleries[0].classList.contains('light-gallery-single')) {
    var $parentNode = getParentElement($galleries[0], 'columns');

    // Check first element have data-group attribute
    if ($galleries[0].getAttribute('data-group')) {
      var groups = [];

      // Getting all data-group
      for (var i = 0, length = $galleries.length; i < length; i++) {
        var group = $galleries[i].getAttribute('data-group');

        // Checks unique group names
        if (!groups.includes(group)) {
          groups.push(group);
        }
      }

      // Start instances for each group
      for (var k = 0, length2 = groups.length; k < length2; k++) {
        lightGalleryOptions.selector = '.light-gallery-single[data-group="' + groups[k] + '"]';

        // if first parent element used, change parentNode to parentNode's parentNode
        if (k > 0) {
          $parentNode = $parentNode.parentNode;
        }

        lightGallery($parentNode, lightGalleryOptions);
      }
    } else {
      lightGalleryOptions.selector = '.light-gallery-single';

      lightGallery($parentNode, lightGalleryOptions);
    }
  }

}

// Finds closest parent element
function getParentElement(element, classname) {
  if (element.className) {
    if (element.className.split(' ').indexOf(classname) >= 0) {
      return element;
    }
  }

  return getParentElement(element.parentNode, classname);
}
```